# right click pan fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I want to be able to replace my onclick button pan with right click mouse.

My current code uses

```
$('#goRight').click(function(){
        var units = 50 ;
        var delta = new fabric.Point(units,0) ;
        canvas.relativePan(delta) ;
    }) ;

    $('#goLeft').click(function(){
        var units = 50 ;
        var delta = new fabric.Point(-units,0) ;
        canvas.relativePan(delta) ;
    }) ;
    $('#goUp').click(function(){
        var units = 50 ;
        var delta = new fabric.Point(0,-units) ;
        canvas.relativePan(delta) ;
    }) ;

    $('#goDown').click(function(){
        var units = 50 ;
        var delta = new fabric.Point(0,units) ;
        canvas.relativePan(delta) ;
    }) ;
```

I want to use this code

```
function startPan(event) {
  if (event.button != 2) {
    return;
  }
  var x0 = event.screenX,
      y0 = event.screenY;
  function continuePan(event) {
    var x = event.screenX,
        y = event.screenY;
    fc.relativePan({ x: x - x0, y: y - y0 });
    x0 = x;
    y0 = y;
  }
  function stopPan(event) {
    $(window).off('mousemove', continuePan);
    $(window).off('mouseup', stopPan);
  };
  $(window).mousemove(continuePan);
  $(window).mouseup(stopPan);
  $(window).contextmenu(cancelMenu);
};
function cancelMenu() {
  $(window).off('contextmenu', cancelMenu);
  return false;
}
$(canvasWrapper).mousedown(startPan);
```

but I dont know how to implement it on to my canvas. Because I am new to fabricJS this may be a simple task, but I cant work it out.

My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wayneker/48agpn5n/3/) or if you look at version 4 you will see that I put it in but doesnt work. Please advise me what I am doing wrong. This is what i am trying to achieve [desired result](http://michaellaszlo.com/so/fabric-pan/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error here:

```
fc.relativePan({ x: x - x0, y: y - y0 });
```

it should be

```
canvas.relativePan({ x: x - x0, y: y - y0 });
```

And after that it does what it should http://jsfiddle.net/n3pryn3x/

Comment: i think i found this the same time as you.. was just logging back in to delete the question and seen your post.. thank you anyway :)